# Syncing Qubole HIve table to Snowflake with Struct field

Tags: hive, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, qubole

I have a table like following Qubole:

```
use dm;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fact (
    id string,
    fact_attr struct<
        attr1 : String,
        attr2 : String
    >
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/DM/fact'
```

I have created parallel table in Snowflake like following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dm.fact (
    id string,
    fact_attr variant
)
```

My ETL process loads the data into qubole table like:

```
+------------+--------------------------------+
| id         | fact_attr                      |
+------------+--------------------------------+
| 1          | {"attr1": "a1", "attr2": "a2"} |
| 2          | {"attr1": "a3", "attr2": null} |
+------------+--------------------------------+
```

I am trying to sync this data to snowflake using Merge command, like

```
MERGE INTO DM.FACT dst USING %s src 
    ON dst.id = src.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    fact_attr = parse_json(src.fact_attr)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
    id,
    fact_attr
) VALUES (
    src.id,
    parse_json(src.fact_attr)
);
```

I am using PySpark to sync the data:

```
df.write \
  .option("sfWarehouse", sf_warehouse) \
  .option("sfDatabase", sf_database) \
  .option("sfSchema", sf_schema) \
  .option("postactions", query) \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .snowflake("snowflake", sf_warehouse, sf_temp_table)
```

With above command I am getting following error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Don't know how to save StructField(fact_attr,StructType(StructField(attr1,StringType,true), StructField(attr2,StringType,true)),true) of type attributes to Snowflake"
```

I have read through following links but no success:

- [Semi-structured Data Types](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html)
- [Querying Semi-structured Data](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-semistructured.html)

Question:

> How can I insert/sync data from Qubole Hive table which has STRUCT field to snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

The version of your Spark Connector for Snowflake in use at the time of trying this lacked support for variant data types.

Support was introduced in their connector version 2.4.4 ([released July 2018](https://github.com/snowflakedb/spark-snowflake/releases/tag/v2.4.4)) onwards, where the StructType fields are now auto-mapped to a VARIANT data type that will work with your MERGE command.